# Heroku Toolbelt Issues on osx 10.5.8

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

So I am just beginning to work with heroku (on an old MBP running osx 10.5.8) and I am having some issues with the toolbelt.  The installation finished with no errors, however I am unable to run any of the heroku commands from my terminal.  I am running ruby 1.9.3 through rvm (if that helps).  The 'which heroku' command gives:

```
$ which heroku
/usr/bin/heroku
```

All other commands beginning with 'heroku' return the following error (using login as an example):

```
$ heroku login
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT trap
```

If anyone could shed some light on this for me, it would be greatly appreciated.  Also let me know if I am leaving out any info.  Thanks!

EDIT:  Also, I did re-install the older version of git for osx 10.5.8 as suggested by many forums and here https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/324 (I know this specific post is pointed at git breaking, however it seemed to be the general answer on most forums that had anything remotely related to my problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was actually a simple fix.  The Heroku gem itself was never installed by the toolbelt (I assume it should have been?).  The fix was:

```
$ gem install heroku
```